# How to break large ".csv" file into small files based on multiple conditions?

Tags: linux, excel, bash, csv, command-line

I have large .csv files (~40MB) and i would like to break them into smaller files by few conditions and name them accordingly to data:

1. Separate file by content of 3rd column,
2. Separate output from point 1 by content 4th colum,

Here's tricky part:

3. Created output by 2 previous operations check if there is any data in 11th column, if yes then separate this data accordingly to content and after that separate that by content of 17th column -> then save outputs
   /OR / AND /
4. If there is no data in column 11 check column 15th and separate accordingly. Next check 17 column and separate this data by 17th column -> save outputs.

I've got something like this in VBA but its too way slow for big files and excel is crashing down sometimes. With multiple files like this it takes ages to cut them down manually and then put in vba into work.

Is this possible to cut files by so much conditions?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Exaple:
(header is # of column)

```
1       2   3   4   11  15  17
Date        Time    COUNTRY CITY    CHECK   TEST    TEST2
2015-08-20  11:54   ENGLAND ABINGDON        1       1
2015-08-21  12:54   ENGLAND BATLEY          2       5
2015-08-22  13:54   ENGLAND FROME           2       6
2015-08-23  14:54   ENGLAND FROME   2       1
2015-08-24  15:54   USA CALIFORNIA          4       8
2015-08-25  16:54   USA CONNECTICUT         4       9
2015-08-26  17:54   USA DELAWARE    1               8
2015-08-27  18:54   GERMANY SAXONY          6       9
2015-08-28  19:54   GERMANY SAXONY          6       10
2015-08-27  18:54   GERMANY SAXONY          4       11
2015-08-28  19:54   GERMANY SAXONY          4       14
2015-08-29  20:54   GERMANY HESSE                   8
2015-08-29  20:54   GERMANY HESSE   1               8

File1                       
2015-08-20  11:54   ENGLAND ABINGDON        1       1

File2                       
2015-08-21  12:54   ENGLAND BATLEY          2       5

File3                       
2015-08-22  13:54   ENGLAND FROME           2       6

File4                       
2015-08-23  14:54   ENGLAND FROME   2               1

File5                       
2015-08-24  15:54   USA CALIFORNIA          4       8

File6                       
2015-08-25  16:54   USA CONNECTICUT         4       9

File7                       
2015-08-26  17:54   USA DELAWARE    1               8

File8                       
2015-08-27  18:54   GERMANY SAXONY          4       9
2015-08-28  19:54   GERMANY SAXONY          4       10

File9                       
2015-08-27  18:54   GERMANY SAXONY          6       11
2015-08-28  19:54   GERMANY SAXONY          6       14

File10                      
2015-08-29  20:54   GERMANY HESSE                   8

File11                      
2015-08-29  20:54   GERMANY HESSE   1               8
```

Comment: Maybe show us 10-20 lines with a mixture of data and how it will look when processed.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I've added "example" in problem description.

Comment: Have you tried anything in bash at all? What's your delimiter? Tab?

Comment: @carlspring I'm new in bash (some really sample cut etc.). I'm more advanced at VBA, my delimiter is TAB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is all over the place! It isn't in the columns you describe and it isn't tab-separated. You aren't making life easy!

Try this `awk` with your real data to see if it generates an output filename that you can use.

```
awk -F'\t' '{
    f=$3 "_" $4                # filename = field3 _ field4
    if(length($11)){           # if f11 not null
      f=f "_A_" $11 "_" $17    #    filename = filename _A_ field11 _ field17
    }else{                     # else
      f=f "_B_" $15 "_" $17    #    filename = filename _B_ field15 _ field17
    }
    print f}' file.csv
```

You should get something like this

```
ENGLAND_ABINGDON_A_3_1
ENGLAND_ABINGDON_A_4_2
GENRMANY_SAXONY_B_5_3
```

Basically it uses `awk` and tells it that your field separator is the tab. It then looks at each line and builds an output filename in the variable `f` by looking at the fields how you describe.

If that separates your data how you mean, you can actually do the output of the current line to the file with the corresponding name by simply changing the last line like this:

```
awk -F'\t' '{
    f=$3 "_" $4                # filename = field3 _ field4
    if(length($11)){           # if f11 not null
      f=f "_A_" $11 "_" $17    #    filename = filename _A_ field11 _ field17
    }else{                     # else
      f=f "_B_" $15 "_" $17    #    filename = filename _B_ field15 _ field17
    }
    print > f}' file.csv
```

Basically it prints **to** the file rather than printing its name if you change

```
print f
```

to

```
print > f
```

**Working out headers**

If you want a header on each output fie, we will need to work a little harder...

First, we need to save the header from the original file, so if we assume that is record number 1, we will do

```
awk -F'\t' '
    NR==1 {header=$0}           # save first line as header
    {f=$3 "_" $4                # filename = field3 _ field4
    ...
    ... as before
```

Now we need to output a header line whenever we start writing to a new file, which is *"fun"* because we just dynamically create the output filename for each line! So, we need to *"remember"* what files we have written to and then only emit a header when we are writing to a new one. I don't have a decent set of your data here, so I am guessing this bit!

```
awk -F'\t' '
    NR==1 {header=$0}          # save first line as header
    {f=$3 "_" $4               # filename = field3 _ field4
    if(length($11)){           # if f11 not null
      f=f "_A_" $11 "_" $17    #    filename = filename _A_ field11 _ field17
    }else{                     # else
      f=f "_B_" $15 "_" $17    #    filename = filename _B_ field15 _ field17
    }
    # Emit header if first write to this filename
    if(!(f in fileswritten)){
       fileswritten[f]++         # note that we have written to this file
       print header > f          # emit header
    }
    print > f}' file.csv
```

Comment: Thank you. I will check that today at free time.

Comment: Mark, I deployed that script and its working, but tell me, is there any way to add header from original file to each file? I mean names of column?

Comment: I have added some code at the end to try and get headers, but it is untested. It should be close enough though for you to figure out if it has any errors.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is incomplete, but roughly illustrates what you need to do:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get list of countries:
countries=`cat file1.csv | cut -f 3 -d$'\t'| grep -v 3 | grep -v COUNTRY | uniq`

for country in ${countries}; do
    # Get list of cities per country:
    cities=`cat file1.csv | grep ${country} | cut -f 4 -d$'\t' | uniq`

    # Get data per country:
    cat file1.csv | grep ${country} > file1-${country}.csv

    # Get data per city per country:
    for city in ${cities}; do
    echo ${country}:${city}

    cat file1.csv | grep ${country} | grep ${city} > file1-${country}-${city}.csv
    done

    # Created output by 2 previous operations check if there is any data in 11th column,
    # if yes then separate this data accordingly to content and after that separate that
    # by content of 17th column -> then save outputs /OR / AND /
    # Column 11 is at position 5 in your data.
    check=`cat file1.csv | grep ${country} | cut -f 5 -d$'\t' | uniq`
    for check in ${checks}; do
        echo ${country}:${city}:${check}

        cat file1.csv | grep ${country} | grep ${city} > file1-${country}-${city}-${check}.csv

        # TODO: Further split this, I assume you get the drift by now.
    done

    # If there is no data in column 11 check column 15th and separate accordingly.
    # Next check 17 column and separate this data by 17th column -> save outputs.
    # TODO: Further split this, I assume you get the drift by now.

done
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I will need to study this deeper later today. By the way, If there is a data between numbered colums, I assume they will be copied over aswell?

Comment: Give the script a go and you'll see. The data is copied, yes. It's very straight-forward, if you play around with it.

Comment: carlspring, I'm checking that script, so far its working, need further mods, but I will ask as I asked Mark, is there any way to add header to each file? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to write a small script and use the java library CSVFormat:

```
private static final String[] FILE_HEADER_MAPPING = {"Date", "Time" ,"COUNTRY", .... };
csvFileParser = new CSVParser(fileReader, csvFileFormat);
        List<CSVRecord> csvRecords = csvFileParser.getRecords();
```

then to access column 11 you have to do

```
 for (int i = 1; i < csvRecords.size(); i++) {
    boolean publishAccount = true;
    CSVRecord record = csvRecords.get(i);
    /// here how to access
    record.get("Fiel column 11");  
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I'll need to check that script too and try which is operating faster. And to be honest I don't know how put your script to work.

Comment: If you create an easy java program you can write this in your main class and simply call it by your unix script. I like this way because it's easy to read and modify. You just need to include the csv library in it. Alternatively, in java you can use the method `split` in the string